# How to check if a value matches a txt file

Tags: python, for-loop, any

Im currently trying to solve a solution where I have a value and a text file (.txt) where I want to check if the value in the code is somewhere inside the text file.

What I have done currently is that I have a text file that looks like:

```
999486
1117978
990583
1128062
1120618
```

and a code that looks like:

```
def filter():

    item_name = '1128062'

    keyword = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('keywords.txt')]

    has_good = False

    sentences = [item_name]

    def check_all(sentence, ws):
        return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)

    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(check_all(sentence, word) for word in keyword):
            has_good = True
            break

    if not has_good or keyword == "":
        print("Removed the keyword - " + str(item_name))
        sys.exit()
```

What the script does is:

that it has a item_name that has a value.
Opens up keywordwhere all the keyword are stored

With the *check_all function and for sentence in sentences:* my idea was to check if the keyword is matched in the txt file. And if it is then we just continue the program and if its not then we print out Removed the keyword and sys.exit the program.

However when I am trying to run this program now I am getting an error saying

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/test.py.py", line 324, in filter
    if any(check_all(sentence, word) for word in keyword):
  File "C:/Users/test.py.py", line 324, in <genexpr>
    if any(check_all(sentence, word) for word in keyword):
  File "C:/Users/test.py.py", line 321, in check_all
    return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)
  File "C:/Users/test.py.py", line 321, in <genexpr>
    return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I realized it must be something issue regarding

```
def check_all(sentence, ws):
    return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)
```

and that's where I have the issue and asking you guys how I can be able to check if the keyword matches in a .txt file and if it doesn't match then we print out *Removed the keyword* and sys.exit the program, if it matches then we don't do anything.

Comment: @NoorJafri Hello! Hmm, Im not sure but I think that is the reason I am getting error since it says on the error output `File "C:/Users/test.py.py", line 321, in <genexpr>` I believe the issue is `for w in ws` which I believe prints character by character?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error when I run your code snippet. Can you try casting your `w` as a `str`? As follows: `return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(str(w)), sentence) for w in ws)`

Comment: Alright so what I just tried and realized is that `for w in ws` does that it loops character by character which I am not sure if could be the reason why it fails? Because I tried to print out `ws` which gave me the whole keyword and `for w in ws` gives me character by character. @Endyd

Comment: Right, since in the for loop, you have a nested for loop, so you go keyword by keyword in the outer for loop (`for sentence in sentences`), and then you go char by char in the `if any` statement when you say `for word in keyword`, which is really `for char in keyword`.

Comment: Yeah I believe so too. I think that sites the problem. So meaning I need to solve somehow that checks if `sentence` is in `keyword` something in that way?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been mistaken. I thought `sentences` was the keywords, but I see that it's just a list of the item_name to be searched. The variable names were confusing me.

Comment: Ohhh, I think I have confused myself more than you actually haha. I think I overcomplicated this more than I actually should. @Endyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the re module here, as it appears we are just searching for a string match.

```
import sys

KEYWORDS_PATH = 'keyword.txt'
KEYWORDS = open(KEYWORDS_PATH).read().splitlines()

sentences = ['999487']

for sentence in sentences:
    if sentence in KEYWORDS:
        print('Removed the keyword - %s' % sentence)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yeah seems like this was the answer honestly! I tried this and ended up having what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you just want to print `true` if the `keyword` is in the file, `False` if the `keyword` is not in the file.. try executing the below code...

text file::

`999486
1117978
990583
1128062
1120618`

program ::

```
def match_string(text):
    result = False
    keyword = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('keyword.txt')]
    if text in keyword:
        result = True
    return result

match_string('999487')
```

`returns True`

**Note**: Still I cant understand whether you need to match a whole string or match each character of a string...

Comment: I just want to match the whole string so it matches the txt file basically :) So etc "123456" need to match "123456" and not by characters! - Btw dont I need to loop through the keyword in that case?

Comment: So the problem here is that it quits the program due to I believe its not looping through the keyword?

Comment: If you want to see if '123456' exists in a file, and the file has a line that is '123456789', is that a match or a no match? If that should be a match, then you would just add `for k in keyword` to wrap the `if text in keyword` and change it to `if text in k`.

Comment: So answer to your question. That should NOT be a match in that case. Meaning that if we want to see '123456' then we just find after a string that has '123456' (Must be exact the same) :) @Endyd

Comment: then the answer lies in the above code.. It just strips all the keywords in the text file into a list and then matches with the required keyword and return `True` if found else `False`...

Comment: Agreed. Accept this as answer. Now that you mention that exact match is desired, you may not even have to do `if text in keyword`, but rather do `if text == keyword`. I would imagine python does a str.size() check first, so it would catch most mismatch cases faster in O(1) time if lengths are different. Checking for `if text in keyword` would be O(n) if `text` is shorter than `keyword`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out :

```
text = "Some dummy text with numbers 123"
tokens = text.split(" ")
num = "123" # Number as string
if num in token:
    print("True")
else :
    print("False")
```